# Two-fold problem with nvidia (high cpu usage) & nouveau (blank external monitor)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nouveau, clone

I am facing two different problems with the nvidia & nouveau drivers. With the nvidia driver, all seem to work just fine.... except one thing: cpu usage gets pretty high, especially when scrolling on any browser (e.g. facebook, youtube scrolling---->cpu goes up to 90+%, starts @~60%). Sometimes, trying to type text, therefore, gets preeeeeety slow. I am sure you get the picture. Yes, I have tried different desktops, other than the default Unity, but to no avail. Cloning my laptop's monitor to an external tv-monitor works like a charm, once I either use nvidia-settings (however, only works for one session and has to be re-done every time!--->I believe I read somewhere that this is the default behavior NVIDIA has chosen...anyways!) OR by manually editing the xorg.file, which I generated (see below). Cloning now works at every reboot/login-logout session. BTW, `disper -c` works great as well. I would be pleased if I didn't have the slow experience, at times, with this driver. Any ideas?

Which brings us to the next issue: the nouveau driver. Cpu usage seems to be better, however, cloning my external monitor gives me a black tv-screen with "no signal detected" (connected via an hdmi cable, which has no problems whatsoever). Hence, in this case no cloning<--->no fun for me . Under "Displays" in Ubuntu, the two monitors are recognized, and choosing "mirror" still gives me a black external screen. I tried with `disper -c`, as well. Still nothing. If I could get some help, to possibly clone my displays I'd be more than happy to stick with nouveau.

The laptop is not to be used for games. Basic usage, which includes surfing the Internet, office docs, "normal" work & movies. I am including some basic info, that I could think of. 
For anything further, please do ask me.

**Specs:**

- Acer Aspire 6935G Laptop
- Processor : 2x Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz
- RAM : 4GB
- LCD Resolution : 1366x768
- GPU : GeForce 9600M GT 512MB

**Note:**

I reverted to the nvidia driver, before posting this thread; hence, the driver tag below. After playing around with several nvidia drivers (all offered from the "additional drivers" of Ubuntu & the latest from NVIDIA's site), I am currently using the latest one from their site, for no other reason than I am fed up (at the moment) . The same behavior I get with Ubuntu's LiveCD, which loads a fresh nouveau driver, thus I am sure the problem has nothing to do with nvidia drivers interefering with nouveau. I am mentioning this last point, to avoid replies to purge the nvidia drivers, whitelist the nouveau driver and etc.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"

$ uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -c video  
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G96M [GeForce 9600M GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:6000(size=128)

$ modinfo nvidia | grep version
version:        340.46
vermagic:       3.13.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i 
vga 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G96M [GeForce 9600M GT] [10de:0649] (rev a1)
```

**With modified Section "Screen", to allow for cloning the two displays:**

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.46  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-03)  Wed Sep 24 14:38:35 PDT 2014


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection


Section "Files"
EndSection


Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection


Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "NoLogo"
    Option         "TwinView"
    Option         "TwinViewOrientation" "Clone"
    Option         "MetaModeOrientation" "Clone" 
    Option         "MetaModes" "1360x768+0+0,1360x768+0+0"
    Option         "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes, NoVirtualSizeCheck, NoMaxPClkCheck, NoWidthAlignmentCheck, NoExtendedGpuCapabilitiesCheck"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**With HDMI cable connected to external tv-monitor:**

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1360 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 200mm
   1366x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0* 
   1024x768       60.0  
   960x540        60.0  
   840x525        59.9  
   800x600        60.3  
   720x450        59.9  
   700x525        60.0  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   320x240        60.1  
HDMI-0 connected 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 580mm x 320mm
   1360x768       60.0*+   60.0     59.8  
   1920x1080      59.9     59.9     50.0     30.0     25.0     24.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
   1152x864       75.0     75.0     70.0     60.0  
   1024x768       85.0     75.0     70.1     60.0  
   960x540        60.0  
   840x525        60.0     59.9  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        85.1     75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0     50.1  
   720x480        59.9     60.1  
   720x450        59.9  
   720x400        85.0  
   700x525        60.0  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        85.0     75.0     72.8     59.9     59.9  
   640x400        85.1  
   640x350        85.1  
   512x384        70.1     60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        72.8     60.1  
   320x175        85.3  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

**More info:**

Same kind of behavior with Chromium. With Firefox it's a bit better (of the order of 20% improvement perhaps). With a light browser, such as Midori, things are much better.

[Firefox Scrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7y45gejs79fb7f/graph_chrome_scrolling.png?dl=0)

[Google Scrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7y45gejs79fb7f/graph_chrome_scrolling.png?dl=0)

```
$ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 9600M GT/PCIe/SSE2
GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, 
GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
GL_NV_path_rendering, GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite,
```